# What are those _report_pb.dump files?

Tags: catalina

In the past few days, there are some files in my `Documents` folder. Typical filename is like: `1400115281_report_pb.dump`, a few digits followed by `report_pb.dump`.

The file seems to be kind of log file where the `1400115281` is `app_id`. Here is a part of the file:

> {"common":{"platform":7,"apn_type":"UNKNOWN","app_id":1400115281,"scope":"common","os_type":"mac_10.15.3","biz_id":"200000001","app_version":"1.3.0.437","net_type":0,"device_name":"x8
>   6_64","sdk_version":18874398},...

What is this file for? How can I prevent it from showing up or default the file to another location instead of the `Documents` folder.

Update, the only Google result about `app_id` `1400115281` is:

[image]

It happened I installed `Tencent Meeting` lately, and the app version is also 1.3.0.437:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it also happened on my mac.

The file occurs everytime after I use Tencent Meeting, you can just delete it.